# Load JSON items in my playlist in the same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I’m doing a small YouTube app with node-webkit but I’m not a master with JavaScript.

I have some JSON objects from `gdata` responses and have items in a particular order, always the same. I can load everything in my playlist but I can’t keep the same order than the JSON object.

I dont understand sync/async calls.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/hM72T6rT

How can I do this with my for loop, so that I get all the items loaded in the same order as my JSON?

The functions are in the order I want:

```
function searchVideos(user_search){
    try{
        $('#items_container').empty();
        youtube.feeds.videos({
                q:              ''+user_search+'',
                'start-index' : ''+current_start_index+'',
                'max-results':  25,
                orderby:        'relevance'
            },
            function( err, data ) {
            if( err instanceof Error ) {
                console.log( err )
            } else {
                items=data.items
                current_prev_start_index=current_start_index;
                if (current_page == 1){
                    $('.back').css({'display':'None'});
                } else {
                    $('.back').css({'display':'block'});
                    $('.next').css({'display':'block'});
                }
                if (items.length < 25) {
                    $('.next').css({'display':'None'});
                }
                for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                    video_loaded = false;
                    truc = function() { getVideoInfos('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+items[i].id) }(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log('searchVideos err: '+err)
    }
}

function getVideoInfos(video_link){
    try {
        ytdl.getInfo(video_link, function(err,info){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                printVideoInfos(info);
            }
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('getVideoInfos err: '+ err);
    }
}

function printVideoInfos(infos){
    try{
        var title = infos.title;
        var thumb = infos.thumbnail_url;
        var vid = infos.video_id;
        $('#items_container').append('<div class="youtube_item"><img src="'+thumb+'" style="float:left;"/><p><b>'+title+'</b></p><div id="youtube_entry_res_'+vid+'"></div></div>');
        //console.log(infos);
        var num=infos.formats.length;
        if ( parseInt(num) == 0) {
                return;
        }
        var resolutions = new Array([]);
        for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
            var vlink = infos.formats[i].url;
            var resolution = infos.formats[i].resolution;
            var resolution_full = infos.fmt_list[i][1];
            var container = infos.formats[i].container;
            // if resolution is alreay available in webm continue...
            if ( $.inArray(resolution, resolutions) > -1 ) {
                continue;
            }
            resolutions.push(resolution);
            if (container == 'flv' || container == '3gp') {
                continue;
            }
            var img='';
            if (resolution == "720p" || resolution == "1080p") {
                img='images/hd.png';
            } else {
                img='images/sd.png';
            }
            $('#youtube_entry_res_'+vid).append('<div class="resolutions_container"><a class="video_link" href="'+vlink+'" alt="'+resolution+'"><img src="'+img+'" class="resolution_img" /><span>'+ resolution+'</span></a><a href="'+vlink+'" title="'+title+'.'+container+'" class="download_file"><img src="images/down_arrow.png" /></a></div>');
        }
        if ($('#youtube_entry_res_'+vid+' div a.video_link').length == 0){
            $('#youtube_entry_res_'+vid).parent().remove();
        }
    } catch(err){
        console.log('printVideoInfos err: '+);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to keep them all in order, you are going to want to use the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async), Look up the async.series function, which should help you out. That will execute everything in the order you give it.